# Problem adding a web reference to an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, web-services

I have seen a lot of similar questions on here, but they seem to assume that the creation of the web service is being tested. I need to be able to connect to an existing web service that I did not create, that is already in use and being used by a lot of systems. This service works, and I'm able to enter the URL in the browser, it returns the XML as it should. When I try to add a web reference (right-clicking 'references', selecting add service reference, then clicking 'Advanced' - I put the URL for the service in the URL box and click the arrow. It previews the XML in the box, and it looks great. However, in the section that says Web Services found at this URL, it shows the error:

> "The document at the url http://xxx:8090/a/b/list (actual server
> address removed for now) was not recognized as a known document type."

The box to add a web reference name and the add reference buttons are both grayed out. How can I get this reference added so I can write an app that browses this service and others (this is the simplest of the ones I need to work with)?

Comment: `they seem to assume that the creation of the web service is being tested.` none of them assumes this, There's no difference between connecting to a test or production service BUT Web References are obsolete since 2010. They refer ONLY to the pre-WCF ASMX SOAP services (created between 2002-2008) and can't handle the WS-* standards introduced later. Are you *really* connecting to such a 12 year old SOAP web service?

Comment: Besides, the URL you posted doesn't look like a WSDL file. When you add a reference to a SOAP service, whether through `Add Service Reference` or `Web Reference`, you specify the URL to a WSDL document with metadata on the service's operations and document definitions. Perhaps someone decided to hide the WSDL file behind the completely unexpected URL `/a/b/list`, but I suspect this isn't a SOAP service at all